# Using Fody to convert a List into ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, fody-propertychanged

Is there any way to make https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged convert a List into ObservableCollection? The core contracts expose things as List and we already use Fody to inject PropertyChange.